# RenderPattern headache with WSS 3.0 Document Library

Tags: sharepoint, wss-3.0, custom-fields

I'm trying to define the DisplayPattern of a custom field to do as follow. It's a simple text field used in document libraries, but i want the text entered to be displayed as a link to the document in the list view.

`<URL Cmd="Display">` gives me the display form, but I want the link to actually download/open the document...

I can't for the life of me figure this one out...

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer lied in `<LookupColumn Name="FileLeafRef" />` used along with `<ListUrlDir />`...